# How to search through arraylist containing string, int and double with JTextField and JButton

Tags: java, search, user-interface, netbeans, arraylist

I currently have a working GUI program that has a few buttons on it to simply step through my arraylist of items. These simply display the first, last or next and previous index results. This list has `String`, `int` and `double` inside of it. Now I have added a `JTextField` for input and a search button. My question is how do I get my search button to search through this array list? I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377831/search-an-arraylist-by-the-contents-of-a-jtextfield-arraylist-containsjtextfi) but I don't understand the datum thing. Do I have to convert the entire arraylist to string before searching through it? Would something like

```
    ArrayList<inventoryItem> inventory = new ArrayList<>();  ....    
    JTextField input = new JTextField(18); ...
          JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");
            searchButton.setToolTipText("Search for entry");


searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String usrInput = input.getText();
                for (String s : inventory) {
                    if (usrInput.contains(s)) {
                        inventory.get(currentIndex);
                        outputText.append(" somehow put whatever the index is equal to here");

                    }

                }

            }
        });
```

The error I get is that `inventoryItem cannot be converted to string`. The second problem: I am having is how to I make it output everything in that index. For example my output looks like this:

```
class officeSupplyItem extends inventoryItem {

    public officeSupplyItem(String itemName, int itemNumber, int inStock, double unitPrice) {
        super(itemName, itemNumber, inStock, unitPrice);
    }

    @Override
    public void output(JTextArea outputText) {
        outputText.setText("Item Name = " + itemName + " \n"); //print out the item name
        outputText.append("Item Number = " + itemNumber + " \n"); //print out the item number
        outputText.append("In Stock = " + inStock + " \n"); //print out how many of the item are in stock
        outputText.append("Item Price = $" + formatted.format(unitPrice) + " \n"); //print out the price per item
        outputText.append("Restocking fee is $" + formatted.format(restockingFee) + " per item \n");
        outputText.append("Value of item inventory = $" + formatted.format(value) + " \n"); //print out the value of the item inventory
        outputText.append("Cost of inventory w/restocking fee = $" + formatted.format(inventoryValue) + " \n"); //print out the total cost of inventory with restocking fee

    }
}
```

I would also like to understand what the datum portion of the mentioned link means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite clear on what you mean by "This list has String, int and double inside of it".

You are comparing an object field with the text entered. You need not convert InventoryItem to a string. What you need to do is identify which fields you want to compare and use them in the comparison.

From what I see the text being entered to the JTextField is the search criteria for your code. If I assume it to be itemName, your code should be as follows :

```
searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
       @Override  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String usrInput = input.getText();
            for (InventoryItem s : inventory) {
                if (usrInput.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getItemName())) {
                    //you can call output string here
                    outputText.append(" somehow put whatever the index is equal to here");

                }
            }

        }
    });
```

This is for the case if the JTextField input is the itemName. If this is any different than you expect, please comment.

From the link you shared, the difference is that his List contains only Strings, that is why "datum" is a String. This cannot be used for your case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My entire code is located here (for ease of sharing) [link](http://pastebin.com/uMXtDJzc) Have a look and see if you can understand what I am trying to do. Sorry in advance for it being so clunky. For some reason it does not like me using s.getitemName()

Comment: getItemName should be a getter method in your class, is it there? Can't open pastebin at work :/

Answer (score 1):

Your enhanced for loop is saying for each String element s in ArrayList inventory... But inventory is declared to be an ArrayList of inventoryItem objects, not a list of strings, and the for loop isn't accessing the variables where the values you are trying to search are stored, as each index of inventory is just storing a reference to an object.

If your main goal is taking input, storing, sorting, and outputting it, you might consider taking and storing it as strings in a string collection. You can always parse to int or double if you need to at some point, but it will be easier to sort and search with a homogenous data type.

Where I saw datum used in that link was just as a variable name, the same way you used 's' in your code.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, what ever the searchText is (itemName or itemNumber) the results should be listed. Therefore,  you could write a search method that compares and returns whether it matches the search string as follows in the InventoryItem class.

```
public boolean isSearchTextAvailable(String searchText) {
    if (this.itemName.equals(searchText)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        try {
            int no = Integer.parseInt(searchText);
            if (this.itemNumber == no) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Not a integer");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can enhance this method to any number of fields you want to be searched within.

Then use this method in the action for the searchButton.

```
  searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            String usrInput = input.getText();

            for (InventoryItem invItem : inventory) {
                if (invItem.isSearchTextAvailable(usrInput)) {
                    invItem.output(outputText);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

You have to make input (JTextField) a field in this class to make it work.

Few tips to increase quality of your code:

- Separate `InventoryItem` and `OfficeSupplyItem` classes to different files
- Notice the naming convention for class names is PascalCase
- Better to have `JavaGUIFixed` class extended from JFrame and all its components defined as fields and not local variables since you use them in various other methods other than `makeWindow()` method where you actually create the JFrame
- Do not use `invItem.output(outputText)` type of methods, where you pass a JTextField to a object Method to write to it. What you could do instead is write a method like `getOutputString()` in InventoryItem class which will return a formatted string of what needs to be printed and then call `outputText.setText(invItem.getOutputString())` - Your implementation is restricting you to have all classes as inner classes to JavaGUIFixed.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have marked @maheeka 's response as the answer. I however had to modify his code because of the way that I had previously written my program. It now looks as follows:

```
searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String usrInput = input.getText();
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++) {
                if (usrInput.equalsIgnoreCase(inventory.get(i).getItemName())) {
                    currentIndex = i;
                    displayItem(outputText);
```

I also had to set up my getter on the itemName as I apparently had forgotten that part. Thank you @Aadi Droid for that.